# Passing in name/id of target div

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to pass in to a $.ajax function the name or id of the target div?

```
function getData(someurl, somedata, somediv){
    $.ajax({
        url:someurl,
        data:somedata,
        success:function(msg){
            $('#id_of_div').show().html(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Have been able to pass in someurl and somedata but as yet unable to pass in the id of the target div.

How should the target div id be passed in?

Comment: is `somediv` your 'target' div?

Comment: Can't you juse code `$(somediv).show()`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can thank people by adding a comment by clicking the `add comment` link just below their answers, they will be notified. You can locate your previous questions (and a host of other statistics and history) by clicking your username right at the top of the page on the grey header bar.

Answer (score 1):

Use the context property...

```
function getData(someurl, somedata, somediv) {
    $.ajax({
        url: someurl,
        data: somedata,
        context: document.getElementById(somediv),
        success: function(msg) {
            $(this).show().html(msg);
        }
    });
}

getData('example.com', { some: data }, 'divId');
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#' + somediv).show().html(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

If somediv is a dom element or jquery object then you can do:

```
$(somediv).show().html(msg);
```

If somediv is the id of the element, then you can do what @boca said:

```
$('#' + somediv).show().html(msg);
```

An example call for choice one would be

```
getData("url", {d1:"",d2:""}, $('#messageDiv'));
```

And an example call for choice two would be

```
getData("url", {d1:"",d2:""}, 'messageDiv');
```